# How can I properly remove the restrictions from a file, get the webContentLink and then make the file private again?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

How can I properly remove the restrictions from a file, get the webContentLink and then make the file private again? by making it private again or setting an expiration time? The setExpirationTime function it's not well documented in php and I don't understand it's parameters..

```php
/**
 * Gets a file download link
 * @param  string $fileId
 * @return string link para download do arquivo.
 */
public function getFileDownloadLink(string $fileId, int $linkExpirationTimeInSeconds) {

    $this->changeFilePermissions($fileId, $linkExpirationTimeInSeconds);

    /**
     * @var \Google\Service\Drive\DriveFile $file
     */
    $file = $this->service->files->get(
        $fileId, 
        array('fields' => 'webContentLink')
    );
    
    return $file->getWebContentLink();
}

/**
 * Handle the file permission stuff
 * @param  string $fileId ID of the file
 * @return void
 */
private function changeFilePermissions(string $fileId, int $linkExpirationTimeInSeconds) {
    $permission = new \Google\Service\Drive\Permission();
    $permission->setRole('reader');
    $permission->setType('anyone');
    
    // what I've tried (not made by me), but doesn't work.
    $permission->setExpirationTime(date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', time() + $linkExpirationTimeInSeconds) . 'Z');
    $this->service->permissions->create($fileId, $permission);
}
```

[Edit] How I'm "bypassing" it manually

```php
public function downloadFileDriveServer(string $fileId) {

    $this->setPermissionPublic($fileId);

    /**
     * @var \Google\Service\Drive\DriveFile $file
     */
    $file = $this->service->files->get(
        $fileId, 
        array('fields' => 'webContentLink')
    );
    
    return $file->getWebContentLink();
}
```

```php
private function setPermissionPublic(string $fileId) {
    //make the file public for a short time
    $permission = new \Google\Service\Drive\Permission();
    $permission->setRole('reader');
    $permission->setType('anyone');
    $permission = $this->service->permissions->create($fileId, $permission);
}
```

```php
public function setPermissionPrivate(string $fileId) {
    $this->service->permissions->delete($fileId, "anyoneWithLink");
}
```

index.php:

```php
echo $fileController->downloadFileDriveServer($id);

sleep(30);

$fileController->setPermissionPrivate($id);
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand the question?  webContentLink is for opening google drive mime type files in the google web apps.  to be able to use that link you need permissions on the file.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo `webContentLink()` is returning me a link like `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=someFileID&export=download`, if I open that link in the browser, it downloads the file

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the details of the current issue of your script? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Tanaike I think they want to use the link for any user without them having access to the file and the file not being set to public

Comment: @Tanaike Okay. 

 I have to provide a download link to my client. The client will download a file located in my Google Drive organization account. But I don't want the file to be always public. I'd like a way to make the file public, return the download link, and then make the file private again, if it's possible... I'd like to make the file temporarily public for that user and then make it private again...

Comment: I'd like somehow to make the process happen in Google's server. Because I'll have multiple requisitions (more than 1000, not in a single file, but more than 1000) and make it in our server would be expensive to us. If theres a more intelligent way to do that I'd like to hear it to, if possible. Thanks!